# SMTP pro not sending emails(Magento 1.9)

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, email, smtp

Magento 1.9

---

**SMTP pro** showing message *"Email sent successfully* !", but actually it is **not sending email** to given addresses.

Comment: i hope there is no smtp pro in magento. Is it a module?

Comment: It is an extention.

Comment: i think there is a test facility at the bottom of the mod configuration. try testing there and see the message.

Comment: Ok I will try for it.

Comment: let me know the update

Comment: Yes sure Shyam.

Comment: you are using Gmail Account ?

Comment: Please accept any of the answer, if it helped out to resolve your issue.

Comment: Yes @MurtuzaZabuawala

Comment: @RajeevKTomy Not yet. When any of answer will solve the issue I will surely accept the answer.

Comment: go to this link and https://myaccount.google.com/security#activity and set `Allow less secure apps` to `on`

Answer (score 2):

> Disclaimer : Third party extension questions are out of scope
>   questions since codes are not available.

Most probably this will be SMTP Settings issue. SMTP Pro already provides a provision to test mails via `System > Configuration > Aschroder Extensions > SMTP Pro > Logging and Debugging`. (See screenshot)

[image]

Also please turn on `Enable debug logging` there. This will give you a log file `aschroder_smtppro.log` under `var\log` directory and it will give you hints to the actual problem.

Hope that helps